# Celery: Updating name of task to match registered task

Tags: python, django, celery

I changed the name of the directory my celery tasks are in which (judging from the error below) has caused some problems with my future scheduled tasks.

```
KeyError: 'utils.tasks.foo'
[2019-02-21 06:25:09,103: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'utils.tasks.foo'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.
```

This task is now registered under `services.tasks.foo`. I know I have more tasks scheduled and can view the task ids in my Redis broker, however when I look at the scheduled tasks using `app.control.inspect().scheduled()` only the tasks that have been scheduled since I made the directory change to `services.tasks.foo` are returned.

Given that Celery isn't recognizing my old tasks, how can I update the task names to match the path that my tasks are now registered under?

Comment: Did you restart celery?

Comment: Can you not temporarily create the old task and just call the new function within it? It will clear out the backlog, and then remove it later when you're confident nothing is in the queue. I might add, this will only work if your queue utilises a persistent cache like redis (otherwise bringing down the message broker will have cleared anything in the queue)

Comment: @YongjinJo Yes that's how the new tasks are registered.

Comment: @Trent Good idea.

Answer (score 2):

That's why it's a good idea to name the tasks explicitely (see [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#names)) as there might be moments when you want to reorganize your code. In the meanwhile, it might be a good idea to re-create old tasks as already suggested.